# Работа с dll библиотекой в среде Dev-C++

Tags: c++, dll

Опишите пожалуйста процесс создания dll библиотеки с функцией

```
int hello_msg()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!!!" << endl;
}
```

и программы, вызывающей эту функцию из данной dll.

В поиске нашел только процесс созданий динамических библиотек в Visual C++. В Dev-C++ создавал проект DLL. Мне не понятно куда вставлять функции, что делать с заголовочным файлом, и как обращаться к библиотекам из основного кода. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прошу прощения за, так сказать, не свой ответ, вот ссылка на другой форум
[ссылка](http://www.sql.ru/Forum/actualthread.aspx?bid=21&tid=390583&hl=) - просто много писать и объяснять. А вообще, советую почитать MSDN или иной ресурс по dll, про раннее и позднее связывание, экспортируемые функции и прочая... Еще, например, [здесь](http://hacker-pro.net/text/get/606/p1.html) - Visual Studio, но принципы использования - одни и те же...